# report file in pdf is unable to open in my website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, crystal-reports

i am working on a website to generate reports using SSRS.

i have three reports. i needed to combine these three reports and form one main report.

I passes the parameters to generate report from my website dynamically, and depending on the parameters ssrs generate three reports. and that reports are stored in a virtual directory. My website works until this correctly. i got 3 reports in my virtual directory.

my problem is that when i try to access there 3 reports to generate the main report it shows the error

> D:\Work\Report\Reporting Site
>   31012017\DAnalytics.Web\reports\a9ecd7da-900d-4530-b191-a08995d309e6.pdf
>   not found as file or resource. "

but in my virtual folder these files are present.

i am using visual studio 2012, SQL server 2008 r2

i am using the code

```
public string MergeDocs(Dictionary<int, string> _Files)
    {

        string _CombinedPDFPath = string.Empty;
        if (_Files.Count > 0)
        {
            _CombinedPDFPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(_Files[0]), "DR_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMHHmmss") + ".pdf");

            //Step 1: Create a Docuement-Object
            Document document = new Document();
            try
            {
                //Step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(_CombinedPDFPath, FileMode.Create));
                //Step 3: Open the document
                document.Open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                PdfImportedPage page;

                int n = 0;
                int rotation = 0;

                //Loops for each file that has been listed
                for (int iCount = 0; iCount < _Files.Count; iCount++)
                {
                    //The current file path
                    //  string filePath = sourcefolder + filename; 

                    // we create a reader for the document
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(_Files[iCount]);

                    //Gets the number of pages to process
                    n = reader.NumberOfPages;

                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < n)
                    {
                        i++;
                        document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                        document.NewPage();

                        //Insert to Destination on the first page
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            Chunk fileRef = new Chunk(" ");
                            fileRef.SetLocalDestination(_Files[iCount]);
                            document.Add(fileRef);
                        }

                        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                        {
                            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,
                          reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
            finally
            {
                document.Close();
                //AddIndex(_CombinedPDFPath);
            }
        }
        return _CombinedPDFPath;
    }
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: D:\Work.... Seems like you are using a strict path instead of server path. Please share your code so I can fix it.

Comment: Can't you make a new report with the others as a sub report?

Comment: "D:\Work\Report\Reporting Site 31012017\DAnalytics.Web" This is where i stored my website. and "report" is my virtual directory

Comment: depending on the parameters my report is also changing. and i need these three reports separately for another purpose @Snowlockk

Comment: Yes you can have the reports like you currently have, just add the sub report and modify the params that you send to it by the params of the master report